# Calling same function more than once

Tags: javascript, function, click, call

Is it possible that calling same function more than once makes click events in this function execute also more than one time?

Comment: "makes click events in **this** function"...which function??

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: in function, what was called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding an event handler in a function, and you call that function multiple times then yes, every time a click event occurs the handler will be called once for each registration.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely unclear.

It sounds like you're asking whether it's possible to bind multiple handlers to the same event.

Yes; every time you call `.on()` or similar methods, you will add another event handler.

Comment: I had discussion with my friend about this question and now I created a example in jsFiddle, but there calling a same function doesn't affect event handlers. http://jsfiddle.net/AkUYe/

Comment: @user2650096: Except when using event delegation, it only adds handlers to elements that currently exist.  Click the last box after adding a few boxes.